# how do i get a list of all of my current blog subscriptions and there current folders and labels programatically in google reader

Tags: c#, api, google-reader

is there a way to programatically get a list of all feeds and there current labels, folders from google reader.  i am using c#.  i see there are some listing for http get / put code but can't find any good parsers as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an interesting [article](http://blog.martindoms.com/2009/08/15/using-the-google-reader-api-part-1/) about using Google Reader in C# directly. You may also take a look at [Google Reader .NET API](http://www.codeplex.com/greader).

Comment: thanks . . i dont see any parsing code here . . what is the recommended way to parse json strings into csharp objects ?

Comment: There are some JSON libraries like Json.NET (http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).